grpc_status:13, grpc_message:"Received RST_STREAM with error code 2"
I have developed a Python gRPC stub that encounters the following exception when used with a higher volume of data (approximately half a million records transmitted over a streaming unary-unary RPC):
grpc_status:13, grpc_message:"Received RST_STREAM with error code 2"
Given that the gRPC server is a black box for me, I can currently only influence the client-side configuration. Are there any client-side settings that I might be missing that could potentially address this issue?
I have tried following stuff:
debug:
os.environ['GRPC_VERBOSITY'] = 'DEBUG'
os.environ['GRPC_TRACE'] = 'all'
os.environ['GRPC_PYTHON_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_SECONDS'] = '600'

grpc channel configurations:
max_send_message_length = 1024 * 1024 * 200  # 200 MB
max_receive_message_length = 1024 * 1024 * 200  # 200 MB
keepalive_time_ms = 60000  # 60 seconds
keepalive_timeout_ms = 20000  # 20 seconds
keepalive_permit_without_calls = True
min_time_between_pings_ms = 60000  # 60 seconds
max_pings_without_data = 0  # unlimited pings
default_timeout = 300  # 
initial_reconnect_backoff_ms = 1000  # 1 second
min_reconnect_backoff_ms = 1000  # 1 second
max_reconnect_backoff_ms = 60000  # 60 seconds

nginx configurations:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-prefer-server-ciphers: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-body-buffer-size: 50M
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 50M
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "GRPC"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout = "86400"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout = "86400"

It's timed out exactly after 60 seconds each time.
